# Can´t create a IoT Hub device group. No supported Device Update tags found

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-hub-device-update

I am currently following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub-device-update/create-update-group) How-to-guide to create a device group to deploy an update to.

All Prerequisites are met and worked flawlessly.
In short. I created a IoT-Hub and created a device update account following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub-device-update/create-device-update-account) , and i Imported a new update described in [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub-device-update/import-update)

But now at [this Point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub-device-update/create-update-group#create-a-device-group-by-selecting-an-existing-iot-hub-tag) I can't proceed, because there are no ungrouped devices detected. I added the tag in the device twin, but still. To give a better inside I listed my current stat below.

**Devices:**
[image: Devices in the Hub]

**partial device twin:**

```
    {
    "deviceId": "1337",
    "status": "enabled",
    "connectionState": "Disconnected",
    "cloudToDeviceMessageCount": 0,
    "authenticationType": "sas",
    "modelId": "",
    "version": 9,
    "tags": {
        "ADUGroup": "MyGroup123",
        "myNewTag": "testing"
    },
```

**The image that should be deployed**

[image]

**The part where no groups are shown**

[image]

**The message I am getting when trying to create a new group**
[image]

**Message routing**
[image]

My predictions are:

1. that I can't do what I want with my 30-day free trial
2. That something went wrong when creating an update instance of my Hub
3. I'm adding the devices wrong

Spoiler they are wrong.

The device update client was missing.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue before, can you check if your IoT Hub has any Message Routing set up?

Comment: I added my Message routing table. But now that you mention it. While creating the instance I think I was told that there will be no routes added. But I am not sure if this was while first creating it or after I tried it again.

Comment: In my case the routes were missing, after they were added I changed my device twin again and then the ADUGroup was successfully picked up.

Comment: Can you show me what your routes look like ? Because at first glance the routes that should be added look like mine. But I will read the doku to this

Comment: They are the same as mine, sorry I got your hopes up. Thanks for updating the question with the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to confirm - did you install and provision the Device Update agent on your device after creating the account?

If so here are some potential root causes why you are not seeing the tag show up-

Ensure that you have correctly configured the message routes in your IoT Hub as per the Device Update resources documentation(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub-device-update/device-update-resources). You will have to tag your device again after configuring the route.

Another root cause could be that you applied the tag before connecting your device to Device Update for IoT Hub. Ensure that your device is already connected to Device Update. You can verify that your device is connected to Device Update for IoT Hub by checking if it shows up under “Ungrouped” devices in the compliance view. Temporarily add a tag of a different value, and then add your intended tag again once the device is connected.

If you are using Device Provisioning Service (DPS), then ensure that you tag your devices after they are provisioned and not during the Device creation process. If you have already tagged your device during the Device creation step, then you will have to temporarily tag your device with a different value after it is provisioned, and then add your intended tag again.

Please find this and other common FAQs at the Device Update troubleshooting guide - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub-device-update/troubleshoot-device-update

If you are still facing issues after following these steps, then please reach out to us directly by filing a GitHub issue here - https://github.com/Azure/iot-hub-device-update/issues

Comment: I have to read up on the Device Update Agent. Because I am following these guides in German. In the last picture you can see my routes. I think they were set up while installing the Device Updater to my IoT Hub. I don't have a group with "not grouped".
Two devices that were connected before upgrading the Hub to support updates and two after.

Comment: The Device Update Agent is missing. I somehow missed this part. I will do this now, but I'm already running into issues because my developing machine is running fedora.